# Drawing HTML with Paint

Tags: android, bitmap, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to draw text on a Google Map Fragment by generating a bitmap and placing it as a marker. However the text needs to be stylized via HTML. I was wondering if this is possible.

```
public static Bitmap createPureTextIcon(String text){

    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    //textPaint.setTypeface(TypefaceUtil.get(m))
    textPaint.setTextSize(MAP_DISPLAY_TEXT_SIZE);
    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

    float baseline = -textPaint.ascent(); // ascent() is negative
    int width = (int) (textPaint.measureText(text) + 0.5f); // round
    int height = (int) (baseline + textPaint.descent() + 0.5f);

    CharSequence m = ViewUtil.noTrailingwhiteLines(Html.fromHtml(text));

    //height * 2
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(m.toString(), 0, baseline, textPaint);
    //canvas.translate(0, height*4);
    return image;
}
```

Example HTML

I mainly need it to render the `<br />`

```
<p style=\"text-align: center;\">Looking<br />at Earth </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a StaticLayout

```
    StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(Html.fromHtml(m.toString()), textPaint, width, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
    layout.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `canvas.drawText(HTML.fromHtml(text), 0, baseline, textPaint);`   fromHTML converts a string of HTML into a Spannable that can be drawn.

Comment: I am, see `CharSequence m = ViewUtil.noTrailingwhiteLines(Html.fromHtml(text));`

It's not rendering HTML at all